# Wifi connection fails every few day. Router reset fixes

Tags: wireless-networking

Every few days, all the wireless devices in my house fail to connect to my Belkin router.  Resetting the router restores all the connections. I get the same result by resetting from the router's admin page or by interrupting the the router's power.

The network diagnostic tool in Windows XP gives the following output:

info Zero (0.0.0.0) IP address detected
action Automated repair: Renew IP address
action Releasing the current IP address...
action Successfully released the current IP address
action Renewing the IP address...
error Error renewing the IP address: The semaphore timeout period has expired.

Mac OSX dmesg gives the following:

en1: 802.11d country code set to 'US'.
en1: Supported channels 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 36 40 44 48 52 56 60 64 100 104 108 112 116 120 124 128 132 136 140 149 153 157 161 165
Auth result for: 00:11:50:1e:66:df MAC AUTH succeeded
AirPort: Link Up on en1
Auth result for: 00:11:50:1e:66:df MAC AUTH succeeded
Auth result for: 00:11:50:1e:66:df MAC AUTH succeeded
AirPort: Link Down on en1. Reason 8 (Disassociated because station leaving).
Auth result for: 00:11:50:1e:66:df MAC AUTH succeeded
AirPort: Link Up on en1
Auth result for: 00:11:50:1e:66:df MAC AUTH succeeded
AirPort: Link Down on en1. Reason 8 (Disassociated because station leaving).
Auth result for: 00:11:50:1e:66:df MAC AUTH succeeded
AirPort: Link Up on en1
AirPort: Link Down on en1. Reason 8 (Disassociated because station leaving).
Auth result for: 00:11:50:1e:66:df MAC AUTH succeeded
AirPort: Link Up on en1
AirPort: Link Down on en1. Reason 8 (Disassociated because station leaving).
Auth result for: 00:11:50:1e:66:df MAC AUTH succeeded
AirPort: Link Up on en1
AirPort: Link Down on en1. Reason 8 (Disassociated because station leaving).

It's a Belkin router.  I don't know if these specs help.
Firmware Version  4.03.03
Boot Version      2.01.03
Hardware          F5D7230-4

I have WPA security on, but that works most if the time.
The router's DHCP function is turned on and the lease time is forever.

Roadrunner claims that their connection and modem are functioning properly - not surprising since the router reset fixes the problem.

Thanks,
Jason

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like your router is failing at a hardware level. Is it hot to the touch?

Comment: That may be.  The router is a few years old and has survived more than one move.  It is not hot to the touch.  I only unplug it for a second or so to reset it.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Belkin web site for firmware updates. Belkin offers about ten versions for your model. You may have an older version. Not knowing the power rating of your power adapter, try increasing it, for example 12 volts dc and 1 amp. Consumer routers are designed with low cost components in mind.

Comment: It's a bit involved, but see if you can put DD-WRT on your router.  I haven't rebooted my Linksys WRT160Nv3 in several months now after I did that, whereas before I had to reboot it at least once a week.