# Could installing DD-WRT speed up my Internet?

Tags: router, dd-wrt, firmware, internet-speed

I believe that my router's firmware is causing me to get much lower Internet speeds than I should be getting. This is true for general browsing, downloading large files and uploading files. Would installing DD-WRT help me see faster overall Internet speeds?

Diagnosis:

- I know the speed is there, because I'm paying for a high-speed cable Internet connection.
- To confirm that I'm getting what I'm paying for, I temporarily removed the router from the picture by plugging a computer directly into the modem with an ethernet cable; I immediately saw a significant and sustained jump in speed.
- The router hardware itself is capable of handling high speeds. I do get good speeds occasionally, mostly right after rebooting, but they never last for more than a few minutes.

Unless I'm forgetting a link in the chain, firmware is the only thing left that could be causing my problem. This is also the conclusion that my earlier questions ([one](https://superuser.com/questions/256517/), [two](https://superuser.com/questions/236627/)) ended up with. Specifically, I think I'm looking at buggy/inefficient code and/or memory leaks, which DD-WRT might not have.

Most of what I've read indicates that the point of DD-WRT is adding features that out-of-the-box firmware doesn't support (and that I don't need), not improving speed. On the other hand, it seems like every web page and forum post I see about DD-WRT has a slightly different opinion of what it does and how well it does it.

I'm asking about only DD-WRT and not Tomato because Tomato doesn't support my router, a Cisco/Linksys WRT160N v3.

**EDIT :**
I am using the latest manufacturer firmware. I also noticed something interesting after I posted this question: although I get great speed when I plug into the modem with an ethernet cable, I don't get improved speed when I plug into the router with an ethernet cable. Could that indicate that a firmware change won't help?

Comment: Its either that or your router is bad.  Do you have access to another router?  If not, flashing the router with dd-wrt wouldn't hurt anything.

Comment: It _might_ hurt; I could always brick the router during the flashing. I don't have another one around.

Comment: Unless maybe the router got some weird setting saved on it?  Have you tried resetting to defaults?  It is actually somewhat difficult to brick your router with dd-wrt.

Comment: Not recently, but I don't recall it making a difference the last time I did.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As long as your router is on the compatible devices list, it certainly won't make anything worse.

That being said, even if a device does report compatibility, I have noticed on a few routers that they suffer from random wireless issues (mainly dropouts on buffalo devices).

Based on the steps you have already tried, I would first check if there are any manufactured released firmwares. If there are, try that first. If not, go for DD-WRT.

I don't think anyone can tell you for certain if the issue is a bad driver/firmware or a faulty unit as I have seen these symptoms for both and it is impossible to distinguish.

Answer (score 0):

I got dd-wrt installed, and I am seeing improved speeds. I don't have exact numbers; I don't know how to run a formal benchmark, and I wouldn't have anything to compare the results to if I did because I don't have good pre-upgrade data. I can say that two computers on my network can now stream videos simultaneously, whereas before, attempts to start a second stream would freeze up the first one.